# Cómo crear cookies en mi web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Yo tengo un pop-up hecho con `html`, `css` y `javascript`:

```
<div class="close" id="close">X</div>
```

¿Cómo hago para que se genere una cookie que guarde la decisión del visitante de que no se vuelva a abrir esa imagen automática en el inicio durante las siguientes 24h?

Comment: Te aconsejo edites tu pregunta y des más claridad sobre lo que quieres lograr, empezando no entiendo cuando dices que se guarde la imagen. Un `popup` no tiene imágenes, te refieres a un modal?

Comment: Modificada, esta mejor asi o la replanteo?

Comment: Pero te refieres a una ventana modal entonces? Si es así, te puedo proponer un código que usa Bootstrap para el modal y PHP para definir cada cuánto (en horas) se muestra nuevamente la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando Javascript puedes utilizar las referencias de W3school:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

y para leer la cookie:

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

Comment: que son las referencias de w3school? a que te refieres con eso?

Comment: @element supongo que se refiere a la [W3C](https://www.w3.org/), mucha gente las confunde, [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/) solo es un sitio de tutoriales, no se puede tomar como doc oficial.